# Is it possible for applying WinSCP assembly to java?

Tags: java, assembly, sftp, winscp

I am new with WinSCP, I really need your help now.

My requirement is that: i need to set up an SFTP server in java environment, after that i will use WinSCP or Putty to connect to it. The user can see all file in folder, upload and download a file.

However, for security, my customer dont want the winscp connect directly into the src folders, they want winscp call functions ( read file, upload and download) through their services (they are written in java), those services will read/upload/download in the src folders and return to winscp.

After research, i found that the WinSCP assembly may help me to modify the ListDirectory, putFiles, getFiles to call the read/upload/download functions in my services. But i didnt found any example in java code. So, is it possible to do that in java? Can you give me some examples?

Thank you very much !!!

Comment: for sftp I used http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Answer (score 1):

Use an api like these ones

- http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/
- [github.com/shikhar/sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj)
- http://code.google.com/p/commons-net-ssh/